# How to validate forms in PHP with $_POST

Tags: php, forms, validation

I'm having a little trouble getting my form validation to work. I'm using PHP I think it has something to do with how I'm accessing my form with the $_POST. I'm using the action and attaching it to a separate page.

HTML

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Grade Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myForm" method="post" id="myForm" action="processForm.php" >
<table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4">
<tbody><tr>
  <td>Assignments:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="assGrade" id="assGrade" value="0" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Mid Term: </td>
  <td><input type="text" name="midGrade" id="midGrade" value="0" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Final: </td>
  <td><input type="text" name="finGrade" id="finGrade" value="0" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" value="Calculate" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP
`

```
 <?php
    $assGrade = $_POST[document.myForm.assGrade.value];
    $midGrade = $_POST[document.myForm.midGrade.value];
    $finGrade = $_POST[document.myForm.finGrade.value];

    $avg = ($assGrade + $midGrade + $finGrade) / 3;

    $grade = '';

    switch($avg){
        case($avg >=90):
            $grade = 'A';
            break;
        case($avg >=80):
            $grade ='B';
            break;
        case($avg >=70):
            $grade ='C';
            break;
        case($avg >=60):
            $grade ='D';
            break;
        default;
            $grade ='F';
    };
    echo "Your average is ".$avg.'<br/>';
    echo "Your letter Grade is " .$grade;
?>
```

Comment: off topic, but `$assGrade` is a funny variable.

Answer (score 2):

The following

```
$assGrade = $_POST[document.myForm.assGrade.value];
$midGrade = $_POST[document.myForm.midGrade.value];
$finGrade = $_POST[document.myForm.finGrade.value];
```

should instead be:

```
$assGrade = $_POST['assGrade'];
$midGrade = $_POST['midGrade'];
$finGrade = $_POST['finGrade'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of problems.  The `$_POST` array directly relates to the `name` attribute in your HTML `input` fields.  Also, the switch statement isn't meant to be used the way you're using it.  Use if/elseif/else:

```
 <?php
    $assGrade = $_POST['assGrade'];
    $midGrade = $_POST['midGrade'];
    $finGrade = $_POST['finGrade'];

    $avg = ($assGrade + $midGrade + $finGrade) / 3;

    $grade = '';

    if ($avg >= 90) {
        $grade = 'A';
    }
    elseif ($avg >= 80) {
        $grade = 'B';
    }
    elseif ($avg >= 70) {
        $grade = 'C';
    }
    elseif ($avg >= 60) {
        $grade = 'D';
    }
    else {
        $grade = 'F';
    }

    echo "Your average is ".$avg.'<br/>';
    echo "Your letter Grade is " .$grade;
?>
```

Technically your switch statement might work, but it's a bit nasty and unintuitive.  Let's assume your `$avg` is `85`.  `($avg >= 90)` would return `false`, comparing that to `$avg` (85) would cause the following condition `(false == true)` which would return false.  The second part of your switch would be `($avg >= 80)` which would be `true`, and comparing that to `$avg` would cause `(true == true)`.

So technically your switch statement would work but it's requiring some strange casting and could be difficult to understand.  If you require a switch statement, I would do `switch(true)` and compare it to the `case`'s you have.

I would recommend just sticking with `switch` statements for very basic one-to-many comparisons and using `if` statements for everything else.

Comment: Really appreciate this thoughtful response. Thanks for the help. Still new to coding.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this block:

```
$assGrade = $_POST[document.myForm.assGrade.value];
$midGrade = $_POST[document.myForm.midGrade.value];
$finGrade = $_POST[document.myForm.finGrade.value];
```

with:

```
$assGrade = $_POST["assGrade"];
$midGrade = $_POST["midGrade"];
$finGrade = $_POST["finGrade"];
```

And also read this: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to the DOM in PHP. You'd access your $_POST variables like `$_POST['assGrade'];` using the parameter name.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$assGrade = 0;
$midGrade = 0;
$finGrade =0


  if isset($_POST['assGrade'])
  $assGrade = $_POST['assGrade'];
  if isset($_POST['midGrade'])
  $midGrade = $_POST['midGrade'];
  if isset($_POST['finGrade'])
  $finGrade = $_POST['finGrade'];
```

instead of your assGrades!

```
$assGrade = $_POST[document.myForm.assGrade.value];
$midGrade = $_POST[document.myForm.midGrade.value];
$finGrade = $_POST[document.myForm.finGrade.value];
```